# Add a decorator with parameters to an abstract class that requires data from the instantiated class (typescript)

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance

I am trying to add a decorator to an abstract class but the decorator requires a value given when the class is instantiated. Here is an example:

```
export abstract class AbstractClass {
    abstract dataNeededFromChild: string;

    abstract implementedOnChildClass(): boolean; // the class instantiated on the child

    @someDecorator(this.dataNeededFromChild) // here is the problem, the decorator needs data from the instantiated class
    _implementedOnChildClassWrapper?(): boolean {
        return implementedOnChildClass()
    }
}
```

The problem is that no matter what I do the best result have been a method with an empty argument on the decorator. The data from the child is not reaching the decorator on the abstract class.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to build? You can't access any properties of the instance, because the decorator is executed on the prototype, not an instance.

Comment: well that is a problem. There is no way I can pass data to the a-bract class from the implementation?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `abstract` or `inharitance`. This has to do with the distinction between `class` and `instance`, blueprint and constructed object. And there are most liekly ways to get to do what you want to do, but for this we'd need to know what the goal is, not just the approach you're taking to get there. That's why I asked what you're trying to build here. Why (and what) do you need the concrete instance in your decorator?

Comment: You can do this with Mixins by declaring that your base constructor returns an instance of a particular type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html